# Placing asterisk to to Lightning:input fields in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, required-field

I am trying to add a double asterisk to lightning:input tags in LWC, by using "required" tag inside the tag i am able to see the asterisk, but two issues with this is i have to show double asterisk to some conditionally mandatory issues which i am able to achieve partially with below approach.

```
<template>
<abbr title="required" class="slds-required">**</abbr>
<lightning-input label="Middle Name" aria-required="true" maxlength="80"></lightning-input>
</template>
```

But primary issue is i want to display these double asterisk after the label but not before the label, is there a work around to achieve this?

[This is a playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Zkx2PlFdg/2/edit) i have created to see above snippet idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `label-hidden` variant and put label yourself:

```
<template>
    <label>Middle Name</label>
    <abbr title="required" class="slds-required">**</abbr>
    <lightning-input label="Middle Name" variant="label-hidden" aria-required="true" maxlength="80"></lightning-input>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround!

Comment: this works well :), thanks